# PHP Query is Not Executing

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a page with the following php code:

```
 <?php

   include ('databaseconnect1.php');

     $sql1= "SELECT Categoryid, Categoryname, Categorydescription 
            FROM Categories";
     $result1 = mysqli_query($db,$sql1);

   if (!$result1){
    echo "<font color = 'Green' .<p> No Category Found, Contact the 
          administrator </p> </font>";
  }

 function getPosts()
  {
   $posts = array();
   $posts[0] = $_POST['topic_subject'];
   $posts[1] = $_POST['date'];
   $posts[2] = $_POST['topic_category'];
   $posts[3] = $_SESSION['userid'];
   return $posts;
  } 

 if (isset($_POST['createtopicbutton'])) 
  {           
 $data = getPosts();

   $sql2 = "INSERT INTO Topics(Topic_subject, Topic_date, 
              Topic_category, Topic_by)
          VALUES('$data[0]','$data[1]', '$data[2]', '$data[3]')";

   $result2 = mysqli_query($db,$sql2);

 if ($result2){
       echo  "<font color = 'Green' .<p> Topic Successfully Created </p> 
     </font>";
 }else{
     echo "<font color = 'Green' .<p> Topic NOT! Successfully Created </p>
             </font>"; //This is the result I am getting specifically
    }                                                   
   }
 ?>
```

and this is the HTML code on the same page:

```
<form method = "post" action = "" > 
   <table cellspacing="15">

   <tr>
      <th>Subject </th>
      <td><input type = "text" name = "topic_subject" /> </td>
   </tr> 

   <tr>
      <th>Category </th>
      <?php echo '<td> <select name="topic_category"> ';

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
       {
       echo '<option value="' . $row['Categoryid'] . '">' . 
             $row['Categoryname'] . '</option>'; 
       }
     echo '</select></td>';
      ?>
   </tr> 

   <tr>
      <th>Current Date </th>
      <td><input type = "text" name = "date" /> </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
     <th> </th>
     <td> <input type = "submit" value = "Create Topic!" name = 
           "createtopicbutton" /> </td>
   </tr> 

    </table>
  </form>
```

The specific part I need help with is that when the "createtopicbutton" is pressed I am only getting the following result:

```
<?php Topic NOT! Successfully Created?>
```

The following is the table structure of the Topics table:[Table Structure from phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crVnN.jpg)

and this is part of the overall database table structure: [Linkages of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7TlJ.jpg)

So far I have tried making sure that all of the brackets are properly closed and changing the syntax a little bit and no success. However the only thing that worked is when I enter data through phpmyadmin it somehow works. So the problem I feel lays with the form. Can you please assist?

Answer (score 0):

```
       <?php
@session_start();
$_SESSION['userid'] = 1;
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "stack";

// Create connection
$db = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$db) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
     $sql1= "SELECT Categoryid, Categoryname, Categorydescription 
            FROM Categories";
     $result1 = mysqli_query($db,$sql1);

   if (!$result1){
    echo "<font color = 'Green' .<p> No Category Found, Contact the 
          administrator </p> </font>";
  }

 function safe_insert($data)
  {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data); 
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data; 
  } 
/*
    you can validate more than this such as the following
   string length 
   use preg match to only validate number but l used is_numeric ie
                if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/",$data)) {
                    return false;
                }
   limit post based on day
   re structure and change mysql to date .
   table name ie tbl_topic    category_id   category_description ... you get the idea   
  and many more 
   ................. happy coding
*/
 if (isset($_POST['createtopicbutton'])) 
  {           
        if(isset($_POST['topic_subject'])  && isset($_POST['date'])  && isset($_POST['topic_category'])){
            $state = true;
            $errors = '';
            if(trim($_POST['topic_subject']) == ''){
                $errors .= "subject is empty";
                $state = false;
            }
            if(trim($_POST['date']) == ''){
                $errors .= "date is empty";
                $state = false;
            }
            if(!is_numeric(trim($_POST['topic_category']))){
                $errors .= "topic category is should be number";
                $state = false;
            }

            if($state){                 
                $subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($db , safe_insert($_POST['topic_subject']));
                $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($db , safe_insert($_POST['date']));
                $topic= mysqli_real_escape_string($db , safe_insert($_POST['topic_category']));
                $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($db , safe_insert($_SESSION['userid']));
                $sql2 = "INSERT INTO Topics(Topic_subject, Topic_date, Topic_category, Topic_by) VALUES('$subject','$date', '$topic', '$user_id')";

                $result2 = mysqli_query($db,$sql2);

                if ($result2){
                    echo  "<font color = 'Green' .<p> Topic Successfully Created </p>  </font>";
                }else{
                    echo "<font color = 'Green' .<p> Topic NOT! Successfully Created </p>
                    </font>"; //This is the result I am getting specifically
                }
            }else{
                echo $errors;
            }   
        }
        else{
            echo 'Something fishy';
        }                                                   
   }
 ?>  

<form method = "post" action = "" > 
   <table cellspacing="15">
   <tr>
      <th>Subject </th>
      <td><input type = "text" name = "topic_subject" /> </td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>
      <th>Category </th>
      <?php echo '<td> <select name="topic_category"> ';

       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
       {
       echo '<option value="' . $row['Categoryid'] . '">' . 
             $row['Categoryname'] . '</option>'; 
       }
     echo '</select></td>';
      ?>
   </tr> 
   <tr>
      <th>Current Date </th>
      <td><input type = "text" name = "date" /> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <th> </th>
     <td> <input type = "submit" value = "Create Topic!" name = 
           "createtopicbutton" /> </td>
   </tr> 
    </table>
  </form>

  <?php
  // sample data //

  /*

CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `Categoryid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Categoryname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Categorydescription` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `categories` (`Categoryid`, `Categoryname`, `Categorydescription`) VALUES
(1, 'fake 1', 'lprem,djbch schjcwdc k'),
(2, 'fake 2', 'kjdncsjkc dcjdjkds dskjsdkj');


CREATE TABLE `topics` (
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `topic_subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `topic_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `topic_category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `topic_by` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `topics`
--

INSERT INTO `topics` (`topic_id`, `topic_subject`, `topic_date`, `topic_category`, `topic_by`) VALUES
(1, 'sweet', 'chiil', 1, 1),
(8, 'jkfdjk', 'kjkjd', 1, 1),
(31, 'klds', 'los', 2, 1),
(32, 'suceess topic', 'date', 1, 1),
(33, 'ksdl', 'sdlksda', 1, 1),
(34, 'melody', 'sdjsjssj', 2, 1);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `topics`
--
ALTER TABLE `topics`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`topic_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--
  */
  ?>
```

Comment: I tried everything you did here yet I am getting the same result

Comment: From my code what's the error  being shown cause l have tested it here and  its working

Comment: Or try changing the environment u are testing